# How I can see every block size of Blockchain in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

When I am deploying my smartcontract and doing some transactions, I can see the transaction details like hash, time stamp etc. But I want to know much size are occupying by every block in the IBM Bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the IBM Bluemix Blockchain service are you using (v0.6 or v1.0)?

Nowadays, IBM Bluemix Blockchain is a Beta solution, so it would have some bugs. However, you should see your blockchain and all your blocks through the Dashboard of the IBM BLuemix (v0.6).

Comment: Actually, in dashboard they are showing so many information except block size.

Comment: I am working on both v0.6 and v1.0, I am trying to collect storage per block and Consensus time for transactions after deploying transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the internal memory used for each block? This information is not exposed by any IBM Bluemix UI for Blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation which provides UI Walkthrough of the Blockchain service on Bluemix: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/v10_dashboard.html

But i don't see the block size being shown on the screen. Not sure if it is by design or its a work in progress. Remember the Blockchain services on Bluemix seems to be in BETA stage as of now. I would suggest you contact support to work with them to see if they can provide you the information you are seeking.